# Do/should index matrices work with xts object?

Tags: r, xts

I am getting surprising results when I use an index matrix with an xts object. See below.

It works as expected if I coerce x to a matrix (unsurprisingly).

Thanks for any assistance.

```
> data(sample_matrix)
> x<- as.xts(sample_matrix)
> i<- matrix(1:4, 2, 2,  byrow=T )
> i
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
> head(x)
               Open     High      Low    Close
2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
2007-01-03 50.23050 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767
2007-01-04 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236
2007-01-05 50.37347 50.37347 50.22103 50.33459
2007-01-06 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112
2007-01-07 50.13211 50.21561 49.99185 49.99185
> x[i]<- NA
> head(x)
               Open     High      Low    Close
2007-01-02       NA 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
2007-01-03       NA 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767
2007-01-04       NA 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236
2007-01-05       NA 50.37347 50.22103 50.33459
2007-01-06 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112
2007-01-07 50.13211 50.21561 49.99185 49.99185
```

Comment: looking at ``?`[.xts` ``, it doesn't claim to support index matrices.

Comment: Thanks mnel - I hadn't seen that page. My real problem though is that I want to assign to the subset, not extract it. Best workaround I can think of is to coerce my time series to a matrix, do the assignment & then turn it back into an xts object.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get a response here eventually, at least one `xts` author is a regular SO attendee.

Comment: I've thought of a better workaround: coredata(x)[i]<- NA works.

Comment: Add that as an answer!

Comment: I've added this as a feature request and noted your work-around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a workaround. Instead of

```
x[i]<- NA
```

Use coredata:

```
> coredata(x)[i]<- NA
> head(x)
               Open     High      Low    Close
2007-01-02 50.03978       NA 49.95041 50.11778
2007-01-03 50.23050 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767
2007-01-04 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414       NA
2007-01-05 50.37347 50.37347 50.22103 50.33459
2007-01-06 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112
2007-01-07 50.13211 50.21561 49.99185 49.99185
```

Though it does still seem to me (a beginner) that xts is doing the wrong thing in the original code.